# Asynchronous Python HTTP post request to IBM Watson Speech to Text service

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I want to simultaneously send X number HTTP post requests to Watson's Speech to Text service. For example, I want to send 20 requests at the same time and get back the responses as they come in.  I've tried a few different methods.  Here's my request:

```
headers = {
'content-type': 'audio/wav',
    'timestamps': 'true'
}
url = 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?
continuous=true&timestamps=true'
r = requests.post(url, auth=(username, password), headers=headers, data=audio)
```

How can I turn this one request to the Speech to Text service into X asynchronous requests?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I've updated my post @kennytm

Comment: Are there any particular reasons you cannot make separate requests that execute in parallel? For example, your app could send many simultaneous requests to the Speech to Text service (with different audio data for each, of course). I assume the Speech to Text service would then transcribe the audio data in parallel and return transcription results as they are produced. Would that not work for your particular use case?

Comment: @GlennR.Fisher yes that is essentially what I'm trying to do. My question is how to make simultaneous post requests to speech to text

Comment: Can't you just make multiple requests? Or is there something that I'm missing?

For example,

`r1 = requests.post(url, auth=(username, password), header=headers, data=audio1)
r2 = requests.post(url, auth=(username, password), header=headers, data=audio2)
...
r20 = requests.post(url, auth=(username, password), header=headers, data=audio20)`

Comment: @GlennR.Fisher the requests block.  and using multiple threads also blocks which I believe has something to do with the threads using the same websocket for http requests.  Asynchronous is key.  You could make multiple requests but they aren't going to run in parallel

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the asynchronous API to the Watson STT service? It lets you push N number of files in a non-blocking way and see the recognition results when they are available, either via polling or callbacks. See the documentation here: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/#create_job